# Logparser - remove file extension

Tags: logparser

The below logparser query is returning the file names accessed from a website.

```
LogParser.exe -i:W3C "SELECT EXTRACT_FILENAME (cs-uri-stem) As FileName FROM c:\weblog\file1.log" -o:CSV
```

Example returned:

```
forum.aspx
example_image.jpg
search.aspx
```

Can someone provide insight on how to remove the extension of the file names from within logparser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EXTRACT_PREFIX function to extract everything up to the last substring separated by '.':

```
SELECT EXTRACT_PREFIX( EXTRACT_FILENAME (cs-uri-stem), -1, '.')...
```